# How to change the title tag on a html page, depending on Div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, title

I have this site [HERE](http://www.screen-size.net/) and what it dose is tell you the size of your screen and the size of your window.

When you adjust your window size the numbers change and is then displayed on the page.

What I want to happen is when you do this, the title also displays the figure.

Similar to this [HERE](http://preev.com/). As you change the number so does the title.

I am not sure how to do this?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thank you

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer once you've got it working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code which changes the title, taken from the site which you provided :)

```
function invChange() {
    changeField = invField;
    var num = rate ? parseFloat(invField.inner.value) : null;
    var prod = num ? round(rate * num, 4) : '';
    with(numField) {
        val(prod);
        gauge();
        if (prod) {
            pulse();
            doc.title = prod + ' ' + cur + ' · Preev'
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
function numChange() {
    changeField = numField;
    var num = rate ? parseFloat(numField.inner.value) : null;
    var prod = num ? round(num / rate, 4) : '';
    with(invField) {
        val(prod);
        gauge();
        if (rate) {
            pulse();
            doc.title = prod + ' BTC · Preev'
        }
    }
}
```

**Here `doc` is variable which holds `document`** (*var doc = document*).

If you want to have look at the complete javascript file then check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kXEzY/)

Answer (score 2):

You just have to look at the source to see how it's done:

```
document.title = 'whatever'
```

Comment: I have done that but I can't work out how they have done it ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update this value using the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/).

In JavaScript you can get the value of this by doing the following

```
document.title="some text";
```

In JQuery

```
$('title').text('some text');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.title = 'whatever';
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].text = 'whatever';
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'whatever';
$('title').text('whatever'); //jQuery
```